# how to create PDF of files in a folder that match range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to ExportAsFixedFormat any excel files from a specific folder if they match from my range B3 to lr. (range is the filename minus the extension)

This is what i have so far. Currently it tries to open each file (not all are excel files, some are autocad) and export the .xlsx as a pdf. It PDFs the current page (which i do not want) and it PDFs one of the .xlsx files from my list.

I do not want to print all excel files from that folder only the ones from the range.

Thanks for any feedback.

```
Sub ExcelPrint()
Dim myFile As String, myFolder As String
Dim LoginName As String, destFolder As String
myFolder = Range("B1").Value
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
LoginName = UCase(GetUserID)
destFolder = "C:\Users\" & LoginName & "\Desktop\_PDF\_Temp\"

If Len(Dir("C:\Users\" & LoginName & "\Desktop\_PDF\", vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir "C:\Users\" & LoginName & "\Desktop\_PDF\"
End If

If Len(Dir("C:\Users\" & LoginName & "\Desktop\_PDF\_Temp\", vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir "C:\Users\" & LoginName & "\Desktop\_PDF\_Temp\"
End If

For i = 3 To lr
    myFile = Cells(i, 2).Value & ".xlsx"
    On Error Resume Next
    Workbooks.Open _
            FileName:=myFolder & myFile, _
            ReadOnly:=True

    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup 'How to print only the .xlsx files from 3 to lr?
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .FitToPagesTall = 1
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
    End With

        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        FileName:=destFolder & ActiveSheet.Name, _ 'How to save as Workbook name?
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        From:=1, _
        To:=1, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
        ActiveSheet.Close
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: How would it open a file which is autocad when you are trying to open it with xlsx extension? doesn't that throw an error? You could use either `FileSystemObject` or `DIR` to check file type before attempting to open the file

Comment: it wouldn't open the autocad file it would just pass by it with `on error resume next`

Comment: I didn't see the `Resume Next` statement! Not something I use often. You don't need that. Like I said, you can use something like `FSO` to check if file exists prior to opening it

Comment: Just a hint (not an answer to your question): Don't rely on `C:\Users\<username>` to be the home of the user docs. Use `environ("Userprofile")` instead. And personally, I don't like it to have anything stored on the desktop...

Comment: @FunThomas thanks for the `environ` tip. Desktop is a temporary location that the user will then print from and move the files to the final location inside of ProjectWise.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with `On Error Resume Next`. For instance, let's say it fails on the first iteration. `On Error Resume Next` will allow it to continue without opening anything, your current workbook would be `ActiveWorkbook` and then it would carry out the rest of your listed operations. Also, `ActiveSheet` does not support `.Close`. I imagine you were looking for `ActiveWorkbook.Close`.

I would suggest using a `FileSystemObject` and checking for the file extension, but if that's not an option, use a legitimate error handler to handle trying to open a non-existant workbook.

```
On Error Goto eHandler
For i = 3 to lr
    'Do Stuff
nextLine:
Next i
Exit Sub
eHandler:
If Err.Number = 1004 Then 'Use whatever error number it raises without `On Error Resume Next`
    Resume nextLine
End If
Msgbox Err.Number & vbcrlf & Err.Description
End Sub
```

Additionally, you could add a variable to store the opened workbook so you don't have to use `ActiveSheet`. This would also take care of your, technically second, question in your commented out line `'How to save as Workbook name?` as you could just use `.Name` prefixed with the variable your workbook is stored in.